# OpenCV kmeans: N>=K exception , error (-215)

Tags: c++, opencv, k-means

My code is following  :

```
Mat cflow; /*computed optical flow */

Mat p = Mat::zeros ( cflow.cols* cflow.rows, 5, CV_32F);
...
...( initializations of p ) 
...


int K = 10;
cv::kmeans(p,K,bestLabels,TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10,1.0),3,KMEANS_PP_CENTERS,centers);
```

And I come up with the following error:

> error: (-215) N >= K in function K means .

Obviously N>=K , but how can I reshape it so that it works ??

Comment: `cflow.cols* cflow.rows` is less than 10. You should add more samples.

Comment: What do you mean add more samples ? In the computed optical flow ?

Comment: To find K clustes, you need at least K points (rows of "p").

Comment: Rows of cflow=288
Cols of cflow=384
 
This is the size of cflow. So both dimensions are bigger than 10 if that's what you mean

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Probably sometime it happens that `cflow` has not enough elements. Put a check before calling `kmeans`

Comment: You were right thank you very much ! It was an error in my  loop at some point and p was 0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the number of (5-dimensional) points `N` (i.e. the rows of matrix `p`) is less than `K`.

Obviously you can't cluster `N (<K)` points to `K` clusters.

Be sure that the matrix `p` has always at least `K` rows, putting a control statement like:

```
int K = 10;
if(p.rows < K) { 
    // can't run kmeans with K cluster... 
} else {
    // kmeans(p, K, ...);
}
```

before calling `kmeans`.